# Set the "key" in Spring Redis

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I am able to store my message using the following command and spring seems to be setting the Key:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.boundListOps("myid").rightPush(mymessage);
```

Is there any way I can generate the Key and pass it while adding the "message" ?

Answer (score 1):

`RedisTemplate.boundListOps(K key)` gives you access to list commands that all get executed against the key used for obtaining the `BoundListOperations`. You can use `RedisTemplate.opsForList()` in case you want to get `ListOperations` which is not bound to a specific key and then call `rightPush(K key, V value)` there.